# Angular 7 Input Mask for phone number

Tags: javascript, angular7, dom-events, angular-directive

I am trying to write code input mask to format the phone number like (123) 456-7890. I almost done.

I created directive to perform the format,
but I'm stuck on the paste operation.

If the user type the phone number in textbox its working fine.

But if the user copy and paste the 10 digit phone number in textbox the formatting happened only in textbox not reflecting in model binding.

textbox show -> (123) 456-7890 but in ngModel bind is 1234567890

Actual code in StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-648zrp

Code

**html template**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<div>
  <span>Copy and paste the below text in textbox </span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>1234567890</span>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
    <div>
        <input name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control" phone autocomplete="off"
  maxlength="14" (blur)="onSubmit()" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"/>
        <br/>
  <br/>
        <span>PhoneNumber NgModel Bind : {{phoneNumber}}</span>
        <br/>
  <br/>
        <span *ngIf="myForm?.controls?.phoneNumber">PhoneNumber form value : {{myForm.controls.phoneNumber.value}}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][phone]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class MaskDirective {

  constructor(public model: NgControl) {}

  onInputChange(value) {
        var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');

        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's the code I wrote recently. It not only validates the phone pattern but automatically adds parenthesis and dashes as you enter numbers

```
public isValidFlg:boolean = true;

validatePhoneNo(field) {
  var phoneNumDigits = field.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

  this.isValidFlg = (phoneNumDigits.length==0 || phoneNumDigits.length == 10);

  var formattedNumber = phoneNumDigits;
  if (phoneNumDigits.length >= 6)
    formattedNumber = '(' + phoneNumDigits.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + phoneNumDigits.substring(3, 6) + '-' + phoneNumDigits.substring(6);
  else if (phoneNumDigits.length >= 3)
    formattedNumber = '(' + phoneNumDigits.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + phoneNumDigits.substring(3);

  field.value = formattedNumber;
}
```

and the input:

```
<input type="text" (input)="validatePhoneNo($event.target)" placeholder="(___) ___-____">
<div *ngIf="!isValidFlg">Invalid Format"</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try @HostListener

```
@HostListener('paste',['$event']) onEvent($event) {}
```

Reference:-
http://embed.plnkr.co/hsisILvtKErBBOXECt8t/